# Newtonsoft JSON package dependency means can't use SignalR with SDK Functions

Tags: package, version

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-rc1-final has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.2), but Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13 -> Newtonsoft.Json (= 10.0.3).

Does anyone know what's in version 11.0.2 of Newtonsoft.Json that breaks SDK.Functions?